# HTTP GET instead of POST occurring randomly

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, http

We started experiencing the following problem since January. Randomly we receive *GET* requests on urls, which should only receive *POST* form submissions. The *GET* request has no parameters (i.e. the form data are not seen in the URL). Such requests lead to exception in Rails routing ("Only post requests are allowed.") and the user gets error page 500.

- The problem happens less than once a day (we get hundreds of *POST* requests every day).
- It seems to happen in multiple browsers (IE7, IE8, Chrome).
- It seems, that reload of the page with the form fixes the problem (I have one confirmed case, when non-reloading the page did not fix it).
- I am not able to reproduce the problem myself.
- The requests come from real users, not robots.
- The form has the `method="post"` attribute.
- The problem seems to occur mostly on one form, but happened also elsewhere.

I checked the page for javascripts, which might do some tampering with form method, but I didn't find any suspects. The site is made with Rails, there is jQuery used.

Any ideas, what could be the problem cause or how to investigate?

Thanks.

**UPDATE:** We run *Nginx* + *Mongrel Cluster*. The *Nginx* `access.log` shows the *GET* requests we observe and there are no related entries in the *Nginx* `error.log`.

Comment: You can add a debugging JS code, to dump the source of the page when it gets back this 500 status message. Then with the consent of the user you can upload it to your site and check if the source indeed contains the `method="post"`.

Answer (score 1):

I detected a similar behavior with Chrome, doing this actions:

1. GET a form (html) (response1)
2. POST form data (response2)
3. POST another form data (response3)
4. Press back

In this case, instead of going back to response2 page, Chrome makes a GET to the address used in point 2.

A similar error occur with a previous Chrome version, when you update (f5) a page made by a POST.

Chrome version: 32.0.1700.76 m

Answer (score 0):

I've seen similar errors on my server. It was about a year or more ago. As far I remember this was caused by our web server. Old versions of [Passenger](http://www.modrails.com/) didn't worked very well with Apache. Passenger upgrade to newer version fixed the problem. Now I've switched to Nginx.

So make sure you have updated web server software, whatever you use. And check your web server logs for errors, not Rails production.log.

Comment: Thanks for answer. We run Nginx + Mongrel cluster. I checked the Nginx error log, but did not find any related entry. The access.log normally shows the get requests.